# Jenkins - Not to have failed upstream job if downstream job fails

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a master job which triggers multiply downstream jobs. If some of the downstream jobs fail, I don't want to have failed upstream job. Is there any condition I could set?[image]

Because of that one failed job, I have this status of upstream job, and I want it to be success.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if you want the the downstream jobs are success or not and you don't want to wait until those finish. then you can use in your master jobs in build job command `propagate: false, wait: false`

Comment: Well, I would like for the caller job to finish when all jobs are finished, I just don't want that status of downstream jobs decides what would be the status of the upstream job.

Comment: @Irene could you paste your jenkinsfile here

Comment: @Irene if you are using the [build](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) command to trigger downstream builds then there is a `propagate` parameter: if it is set to `false` then the build step succeeds even if the downstream build failed.